# How to use inner join to get 'next column' value?

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, inner-join

I've been researching for quite some time and it seems I may be misunderstanding how inner-joins work in MySQL.

I have 3 tables:

**UserTable:**

```
UserID        UserName        Hash        UserUni        UserHousing
1               John         @123eq..       FK               FK
2               Bob          !S91ka..       FK               FK
...
```

The foreign keys relate to the following two tables' PKs (UniID and HousingID, respectively):

**UniversitiesList:**

```
UniID        UniName 
1           Yale  
2           Penn  
...
```

**HousingList:**

```
HousingID   HousingName        UniID 
1           Dorm_1             FK
2           Dorm_2             FK
...
```

Where, of course, these FKs are PKs (UniID) in Universities list

What I'm trying to do is query the id, hash, UserUni, and UserHousing *values*, i.e not the keys. This is what I'm playing around with now:

```
"SELECT UserTable.Hash, UserTable.UserID, UserTable.UserUni, UserTable.UserHousing "
        + "FROM UserTable "
        + "INNER JOIN UniversitiesList "
        + "ON UserTable.UserUni = UniversitiesList.UniID "                                        
        + "INNER JOIN HousingList " 
        + "ON UserTable.UserHousing = HousingList.HousingID "   
        + "WHERE UserTable.UserName = John"
```

What I would like to retrieve is something like `1, @123eq, Yale, Dorm_1`, but instead I keep getting `1, @123eq, 1, 1`.

I'm working with Java so this is how I'm getting the results:

```
if (result.next()) {
    hash = result.getString(1);
    id = result.getInt(2);
    uni = result.getString(3);
    housing = result.getString(4);
}
```

Any idea one what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your query to this:

```
"SELECT UserTable.Hash, UserTable.UserID, UniversitiesList.UniName, HousingList.HousingName "
        + "FROM UserTable "
        + "INNER JOIN UniversitiesList "
        + "ON UserTable.UserUni = UniversitiesList.UniID "                                        
        + "INNER JOIN HousingList " 
        + "ON UserTable.UserHousing = HousingList.HousingID "   
        + "WHERE UserTable.UserName = John"
```

As written, you're only asking for the columns in your UserTable, not the other tables. The joins look ok from what I can tell...

Comment: Ryan...I'm setting an alarm for 8 minutes from now to mark your answer as correct (not sure why it won't let me do it now). Thank you very much! For education's sake, the elements that come after the "SELECT" statement should always come from the table I want them - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the elements following SELECT are used to indicate which columns you want in your result set. You need to specify the table they belong to in order to resolve any column name abiguity (IE, two tables might have an "ID" field). Also, as an aside, you can also alias the table name to something shorter and easier to use by adding `AS <shortname>` after the table name in your statement. Then you can use `<shortname>` to identify the column name. Ex: `SELECT U.UserID FROM UserTable AS U WHERE U.UserName = 'John'"`

Comment: thanks for the reply and the tip! will use that moving forward. Have a great rest of the weekend!